# ng-bootstrap shows http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/modal.js 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng2-bootstrap

I have followed the instructions given here properly (https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/) but when i try to use ModalDirective

```
import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap/modal';
```

In my component i keep getting error

```
 http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/modal.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Why is it showing modal.js not found,

i have configured

```
'ng2-bootstrap':              'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap',
```

in systemjs under map

and

```
'ng2-bootstrap':              { format: 'cjs', main: 'bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
```

under packages